# How can you pass an int variable into a function with float parameters in C++ without getting compile errors?

Tags: c++

My professor gave us two examples of code in which both pass the int
values, x & y, into a function with float parameters as examples of
how to pass a different type of variable into a function by reference. I've ran them both, and neither work, unless of course I change `int x, y;` to `float x, y;`. The programs are written in C.

In his notes, following the 2nd program, he makes his point regarding the comparison of the 2:

**"It (both programs) prints out:  normalized vector = ( .12, .16 )
This code is nearly identical to the code of the previous example.  The difference is in the way the parameters are declared in the normalizeVector function.  By using the "&" operator, the normalizeVector function has access to the variables being passed to it, not just access to the values of those variables, access to the original location.  This is functionally the same as having the address of those variables, but the syntax is nicer for those not used to using C pointers.  Since the "&" is used, all of the work de-referencing the variables using the "*", as in the previous example, can be avoided."**

While I am not questioning the rule or technique, I can't run them and am dying to know what stupid little mistake I am making or what crazy (and probably very simple) detail I am missing. I have done much more than just copy and paste them. Not to mention, when I used `int` `float` to make them work, I had to remove the `sqrt` before `(xWork*xWork + yWork*yWork)` in order to get the correct answers. (And by the way, he is a great professor.) Should these programs work? And how do I pass `int` into `float` parameters by reference, if they don't?

#### Program 1

```
main()
{
    int x, y;   
    x = 3;
    y = 4; 

    normalizeVector(&x, &y);    
    printf(“normalized vector = ( %f, %f ) \n”, x, y);
}  

void normalizeVector(float *x, float *y)
{
    float magnitude;
    float xWork, yWork;
    xWork = *x;
    yWork = *y; 

    magnitude = sqrt(xWork*xWork + yWork*yWork);
    *x = xWork/magnitude;
    *y = yWork/magnitude;
}
```

#### Program 2

```
main()
{
    int x, y;    
    x = 3;
    y = 4;

    normalizeVector(x, y);
    printf(“normalized vector = ( %f, %f ) \n”, x, y);
}  

void normalizeVector(float &x, float &y)
{
    float magnitude;
    float xWork, yWork;
    xWork = x;
    yWork = y;

    magnitude = sqrt(xWork*xWork + yWork*yWork);
    x = xWork/magnitude;
    y = yWork/magnitude;
}
```

Comment: The second program is using C++ notation but is invalid C++ because `normalizeVector()` is not declared before it is used and it doesn't specify the return type of `main()`. The first program is not strictly valid in modern C (meaning C99 or C11). Again, there should be a return type for `main()` and you should declare `normalizeVector()` before trying to use it. Invalid code makes it hard to get good answers. Omitting the headers is unnecessary if there are only a couple needed, as in the example programs. You get away with blue murder in C because you weren't compiling with warnings.

Comment: While I was editing, I couldn't work out what you really meant by _"Not to mention, when I used `int` `float` to make them work, I had to remove the `sqrt` before `(xWork*xWork + yWork*yWork)` in order to get the correct answers."_ so I left it alone; you should fix it.

Comment: In C, if you're passing values by reference, you have to have a variable of the correct type to hold the value so that you can pass the address of the variable.  It's slightly complicated by the presence of compound literals in C99 and later, but that's similar.  You can't pass an `int` by reference to a function that expects a `float` by reference.  Period.  Of course, the compiler must know what's expected to be able to give the diagnostic, but C++ requires that and modern C coding style definitely prefers to have the information around too — function prototypes are good and should be used.

Comment: The socond program is not C, but C++. C does not support references or pass-by-reference, it is strictly pass-by-value. Your `main` functions have long time deprecated (ca. 28 years) pre-standard signatures and you should have prototypes. If that's what ypur prof gave you, I'd recommend to find a better course. And you lack a **specific** problem description.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I should explain that it is common in the professor's notes for his code to "psuedo code'ish", as he might say. So as for leaving out the declaration, that is assumed. What I have come to realize from your comments, and others, is that I was misunderstanding the point being made, thinking that it was literally **about** passing an int into a different type. He is only making the demonstration of passing by reference, and I believe the "int" is a typo. Thanks so much. And, I learned a lot from your comments beyond that.

Comment: It's very hard for us to debug someone else's eccentric pseudo-code, especially when it is not clearly marked as pseudo-code. Glad you're sorted out, but please be extraordinarily careful about asking if the code isn't 'real' code — people on SO are bound to assume it is real code, and critique accordingly, and if you post pseudo-code, you're likely to get pseudo-answers.  I am not sure whether you're being taught well; it depends on the terms and conditions the professor set down when starting the course.  I'm a bit worried, though, about you being given 'almost but not quite working code'.

Answer (score 3):

Either this code was copied wrongly or the professor is confused.

C and C++ both have some limited rules allowing built in type numeric arguments to functions which are passed by value to be implicitly converted to the needed type, if they are compatible according to a set of parameters explained in the spec (which I wont go into here due to their complexity).

This does not apply to parameters passed by pointer or reference, you need to pass in a pointer to the exact type the function needs if it is passed by reference (there are a few implementation defined tricks involving reinterpret casts but this is unimportant for this case).

So yes, you are correct, the only way this code could possibly work is if you change the variables to the correct type or change the type the function requires.

Comment: Thank you @Vality. I was literally driving myself crazy assuming it was me. Again, he is a great professor, which is why I was in disbelief.